# How can I get value through JSON array like query

Tags: jquery, html, json

Sorry for my English. 
I have a Json Array :

```
"computers":
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "laptop",
        "manufactor":
        [
            {
                id: "m_1",
                name: "HP"
            },
            {
                id: "m_2",
                name: "Sony"
            }
        ] 
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "desktop",
        "manufactor":
        [
            {
                id: "m_3",
                name: "Apple"   
            },
            {
                id: "m_4",
                name: "Tiger"   
            }
        ] 
    }
]
```

Could you tell me how can I do it like this: load computers data >> get 2 computer id 1 and 2 >> choose computer id = 1 >> load the manufactor of that computer.
I can do it with mysql query but in json i don't know how to do that.
Thanks for Suggestion!

Edit: I want to retrieve the manufacturer of the computer with ID - 1 from the JSON object above.

Thank to everyone for helping me out.
I am going to create a page working with JSON look like DOJOX Rolling list, would you give me example or suggestion how to do like that ?
thank you:D

Comment: Was your question answered? If so, please click the check mark next to the best answer to mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 9):

Using:

```
computers[0].manufactor[0].name
```

Will return "HP".

If you change it to:

```
computers[0].manufactor[1].name
```

You will get "Sony".

Changing it further to:

```
computers[1].manufactor[0].name
```

will return "Apple".

And finally:

```
computers[1].manufactor[1].name
```

returns "Tiger".

Look here for [more](http://www.json.org/js.html) information on how to manipulate JSON objects with Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Say the given JSON data is in var `data = {your give json string here};` and you want to access the `computers` array from `data`.

Array `computers` is accessed using

```
alert(data.computers);
```

For accessing the manufacturer, use the following:

```
for (var i in data.computers){
var id= i.id; /*returns id*/
var type = i.type;/*returns type*/
var manufactor = i.manufactor;/*returns munufactor i.e. an array*/
/*MANUFACTOR IS ARRAY SO YOU MAY USE*/
for (var j in manufactor){
    var m_name = j.name; /*returns manufactor's name*/
    var m_id = j.id; /*returns manufactor's id*/
}}
```

That is used if you have unknown number of computers and manufacturer in an array.

Answer (score 1):

computer[1].id
read more : http://www.json.org/fatfree.html

Comment: computer[1].id will only return the value of the id, ie 1 or 2. He wants the manufacturer so will have to go further into the object.

Comment: I know Kevin. What I gave was just a hint towards the answer, so he could learn on his own. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonData = yourJsonData;
//Looking through computers
for(var i = 0; i<jsonData.computers.length; i++)
{
var id= jsonData.computers[i].id; // Get Id
var type = jsonData.computers[i].type; // Get Type
var manufacturers = jsonData.computers[i].manufactor; // Get manufacturers array
//Looking through manufacturer in computers
for (var j=0; j< manufacturers.length; j++ ){
   var manufacturer_id = manufacturers[j].id;   // Get manufacturer's Id
   var manufacturer_name = manufacturers[j].name;  // Get manufacturer's name
  }
}
```