# Access JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am using $.post() jQuery function. I am getting below data

while I am alerting returned data using code `alert(data);`.

`[{"sn":"2","res_id":"101","res_owner_id":"28","res_address":"uk,london"}]`

I would like to get single data value like `sn` = 2.

I tried with code `alert(data[0].sn);`

I read below stackoverflow posts.

[How can I get value through JSON array like query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177993/how-can-i-get-value-through-json-array-like-query)

[Search an array for matching attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166765/search-json-array-for-matching-attribute)

[get one item from an array of name,value JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075485/get-one-item-from-an-array-of-name-value-json)

But could not find any solution.

Could anyone help me to get single data??

Thanks

Comment: what you received is purely string, it is not an object yet. use the parse method to convert it to an object based on json standard. then you can treat it as object and use . (dot) to access the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your data seems to be not a `JavaScript object` (it is string) first convert your data to `JavaScript object` with `JSON.parse(data)` then `alert(data[0].sn)`

Comment: sMr has it entirely backwards. It **is** JSON formatted, it needs converting to a JavaScript array.

Comment: @Quentin no if it was  a json object at alert message the user should see an message like object [] object.

Comment: I think sMr calls a "JavaScript object" a "JSON object", hence the confusion. There is no "JSON object". There is "JSON string" and "JavaScript object". JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation".

Comment: @Quentin I think you mean Object

Comment: @superphonic — I don't. The outside of the JSON text is `[]` not `{}`.

Comment: What the OP has is a "JSON text expressed as a JavaScript string". That JSON text contains a JSON array containing a JSON object which contains several JSON strings.

Comment: @rid you're right sorry for confusion that i create...i hurried up to post the answer without reading it...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the JSON string to turn it into a JavaScript object.

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
alert(data[0].sn);
```

jQuery should be able to do that for you automatically though, if you specify `dataType` to be `json` while calling the [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `alert`, you are getting a string containing your data (and not `[Object object]` or similar). This means that jQuery hasn't recognised the response as JSON so it hasn't parsed it.

You should fix this on the server by making the response have a `Content-Type: application/json` HTTP response header.

You could hack this by adding `"JSON"` as the fourth argument to `$.post` (to tell jQuery to ignore what the server says the data is and parse it as JSON anyway).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery, you can use

```
var new_data = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(new_data[0].sn);
```